# Easysnmp installation failed using pip in mac

Tags: pip, snmp, net-snmp, easysnmp

I'm trying to pip install easysnmp. I've already installed net-snmp and gcc with its latest version. I'm getting the following error.

```
      error: /Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/usr/bin/otool-classic: can't open file: build/lib.macosx-13-arm64-cpython-310/easysnmp/interface.cpython-310-darwin.so (No such file or directory)
      Traceback (most recent call last):
        File "<string>", line 2, in <module>
        File "<pip-setuptools-caller>", line 34, in <module>
        File "/private/var/folders/hz/w1sgkjbx5mdbwwmkrghb2j3m0000gn/T/pip-install-r3syy2lu/easysnmp_7cd15fcc88384ce19ce8588bd0e6c2b3/setup.py", line 179, in <module>
          linked, target_lib, b.build_platlib, ext),
      NameError: name 'target_lib' is not defined. Did you mean: 'target_libs'?
```

I'm using macos ventura on m1 if it matters.

Comment: https://github.com/easysnmp/easysnmp/issues/171

Comment: Also having this issue. That linked Github issue unfortunately has no working solution posted to it, just a custom test build that was created for the issue creator (which the dl link now 404's). I brew installed `net-snmp 5.9.3` and `gcc` as well. I've updated `PATH` to include the `net-snmp/bin` and `net-snmp/sbin` directories as Homebrew instructs. Pip install still not working with the exact error posted here.